# Translating custom validations in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, translation, laravel-5.3, multilingual, laravel-validation

I have created a custom validation that is working just fine for the english language but i am unable to figure out a way to do this in more languages.

Changing the language should display the errors in the selected language.

Here's the customvalidation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Validators;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
class CustomValidator extends Validator
{

        private $_custom_messages = array(
            "alpha_dash_spaces" => "The :attribute may only contain letters, spaces, and dashes.",
            "alpha_num_spaces" => "The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.",
        );

        public function __construct( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages = array(), $customAttributes = array() ) {
            parent::__construct( $translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes );

            $this->_set_custom_stuff();
        }

        /**
         * Setup any customizations etc
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function _set_custom_stuff() {
            //setup our custom error messages
            $this->setCustomMessages( $this->_custom_messages );
        }

        /**
         * Allow only alphabets, spaces and dashes (hyphens and underscores)
         *
         * @param string $attribute
         * @param mixed $value
         * @return bool
         */
        protected function validateAlphaDashSpaces( $attribute, $value ) {
            return (bool) preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z\s-_]+$/", $value );
        }

        /**
         * Allow only alphabets, numbers, and spaces
         *
         * @param string $attribute
         * @param mixed $value
         * @return bool
         */
        protected function validateAlphaNumSpaces( $attribute, $value ) {
            return (bool) preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/", $value );
        }
}
```

I have also copied the validation.php in it's language folder 'resources/lang/no/validation.php' and also defined both the validations in the file as

```
return array(
    'alpha_dash_spaces'             => 'Other language',
    'alpha_num_spaces'           => 'Other language',
```

My locale middleware is properly set and i can use trans('myproject.validation.email') to call the translation in view files

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App;
use Closure;
use Session;

class SetLocale
{
    protected $languages = ['en', 'no'];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('locale') && in_array(Session::get('locale'), $this->languages)) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your language in the config file and add that folder in the lang directory.

Comment: Could you please explain more ? I have already prepared the language directory and as i mentioned in my question that the translation works in the view but i am unable to figure out the way to do it for my custom validation method that is showing just english regardless of the selected language